# Regex in case statement

Tags: bash, regular-expression, case

I'm having a hard time getting regex matches to work in a bash case statement.

Example code:

```
#!/bin/bash                          

str='    word1 word2'

echo "With grep:"
echo "$str" |grep '^\s*\<word1\>'

echo "With case:"
case "$str" in
    '^\s*\<word1\>') echo "$str" ;;
esac
```

The example works with grep, but not with case... I'm confused, because some simpler regexes work with case. Does case use a different syntax for regex? Am I just not escaping things properly?

Comment: `case` does not support regex, it supports shell globbing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because `case` doesn't use regex's but bash *Pathname Expansion*. You can learn more from bash man page or from [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-pathname-expansion).