# Case statement allow only alphabetic characters?

Tags: bash, case

```
case "$1" in
all)
  echo "$1"
  ;;
[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z])
  echo "$1"
  ;;
*)
  printf 'Invalid: %s\n' "$3"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

With this the only input accepted is all, and 6 characters. It won't accept 4 characters or more than 6.

What I want to do here is to only allow characters, not digits or symbols, but of unlimited length.

What is the correct syntax? Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289026/regex-in-case-statement?rq=1 May be of help

Comment: @Guy that does explain a lot, why bash has to be so weird? But I'm sure there must be some workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the standard pattern match by looking for any of the non-allowed characters, and rejecting the input if you find any. Or you can use [extended globs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) (`extglob`) or regexes and explicitly make sure the whole string consists of characters that *are* allowed.

```
#/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob globasciiranges
case "$1" in *([a-zA-Z]))    echo "case ok" ;; esac
[[ "$1" = *([a-zA-Z]) ]]  && echo " [[  ok"
[[ "$1" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]*$ ]] && echo "rege ok"
```

`globasciiranges` prevents `[a-z]` from matching accented letters, but the regex match doesn't obey it. With the regex, you'd need to set `LC_COLLATE=C` to prevent matching them.

All of those allow the empty string. To prevent that, change the asterisks to plusses (`*` to `+`).

Comment: Thanks, just enabling the extglob thing and replacing my `[a-z]` stuff to `*([a-zA-Z]))` solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

*digits* or *symbols* are characters. It  looks like you want either:

1. only alphabetical characters (`[[:alpha:]]`)
2. or possibly alphabetical characters but only in the latin script (as your `a-z` suggests)
3. or possibly alphabetical character in the latin script and without diacritics.

Unless the locale is C/POSIX what `[a-z]` matches is more or less random in `bash` (on GNU systems at least).

For 1, you'd want:

```
die() {
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "$1"
  exit 1
}
case $string in
  ("") die "Can't be empty";;
  (*[![:alpha:]]*) die "contains non-alphabetical characters";;
  (*) echo OK
esac
```

That would accept `all`, `Stéphane` (Latin script), `γράμμα` (Greek script), `письмо` (Cyrillic), but not `foo-bar`, `123`...

2 can be tricky, especially if you want to consider combining diacritics.

For 3, for it to run in any locale, you'd need to specify the characters you want:

```
ok=abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

and in the `case` statement, use

```
(*[!$ok]*) die "contains characters not allowed";;
```

Or you could switch to `zsh` where ranges like `[a-zA-Z]` are based on character code points, so always only include abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz or with bash 4.3 or newer [use the`globasciiranges` option to have the same behaviour in `bash`](/a/227076).

Comment: @Freedo, what's a word between A-Z, do you mean a capital letter in the English alphabet between A and Z. Does that include É?

Comment: @roaima anything between a-z, without accents or other weird stuff. Stéphane your last code, it's replacing my * case or the [a-z] stuff? A-Z i want to match too

Comment: @Freedo you keep swapping between `a-z` and `A-Z`. So presumably you don't mind about the case of the letters?

Comment: Bash also has `globasciiranges`, which should disable the locale-specific behaviour in `[a-z]`. `bash -c 'shopt -s globasciiranges; [[ ä = [a-z] ]] || echo no match'` prints `no match` on my system (`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`)

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it works and it's "easier", but I'm sure this will help others with more advanced needs. Thanks for the effort and no offense!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash` or equivalent, include at the top of your script the line `set -s extglob` in order to enable extended *globbing* ( a form of regular expression ), and then in your `case` statement, set your selector to be `+([[:alpha:]])`, followed of course by the `)` required by the `case` statement itself.

`alpha` is one of several *character classes* defined in the `bash` man pages. It encompasses all alphabetic characters, upper and lower case, of your locale.